# Error opening a file residing under "/sys/" in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, file, io

I cannot read from a file resides under `/sys`(to be precise `/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/capacity`).I've tried both using the C method(`fopen` and `fread`) and the C++ method(`std::ifstream`).Here's what I've done so far :

```
//headerfile.h
protected:
    char m_path[150];
    QString m_temp;
    std::string m_temp_str;
    FILE *m_pipePtr;
    std::ifstream m_batPtr;
```

```
//Inside a member function definition :
...
    m_pipePtr = popen("find /sys 2>/dev/null | grep \"BAT0/capacity\" | grep -v \"capacity_level\"" , "r");
    if(m_pipePtr == NULL){
        qDebug() << "Cannot read the battery percentage\n" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    fgets(m_path , sizeof(m_path) , m_pipePtr);

...

    m_batPtr.open(m_path);
    qDebug() << m_path << endl;      //Path is correct
    m_batPtr >> m_temp_str;
    std::cout << m_temp_str << std::endl;         //Empty
    m_temp = QString::fromStdString(m_temp_str);
    qDebug() << m_temp << endl;      //Empty too
    return m_temp;
```

I can `cat` that file and it returns the desired results.Also the following program works as expected(seems strange but `fread` works fine here but not in the above file):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(){
    FILE *fp2;
    fp2 = fopen("/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/capacity" , "r");
    char temp[4];
    fread(temp , 3 , 1 , fp2);
    printf("%s\n" , temp);
    fclose(fp2);
}
```

What's wrong with that?

---

**EDIT:** Output of this:

```
m_batPtr = fopen(m_path , "r");
std::cout << m_path << std::endl;
Q_ASSERT(m_batPtr);
```

is:

```
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/capacity

ASSERT: "m_batPtr" in file ../batpercindicator/batperc.cpp, line 18
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And in both scenarios(C and C++) the problem is that the file cannot be opened.

Comment: Could you please check the return values of read functions (C way) or the stream status (C++ way)?

Comment: @SergeBallesta How can I check the **stream status**?

Comment: Any stream has a `rdstate` member function that returns the status flags, or you can test individually with the following member functions: `good`, `bad`, `fail`, `eof`.

Comment: How is `m_path` set? Sure that it is the right encoding (not UTF-16 or something) and null-terminated?

Comment: @Erlkoenig Information added to the post.

Comment: Show some [mre] in your question, and give also the output of relevant commands such as [ls(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) or [stat(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch [batperc.cpp](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/sYYrFBg2tb/) , [batperc.h](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/vqBrq5C2mm/) and the [output of **ls** and **stat**](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/46Xfq4snS4/).But full reproduction requires QML and QMake.

Comment: Put that in your question please. Don't comment your own question. My recommendation: publish on [github](https://github.com/) the entire source code of your application with some [open source](https://opensource.org/) license.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch [Repo](https://github.com/P-Mousavi/batpercindicator_git) is ready.

Comment: But still not mentioned in your question. You are naive in expecting us to do your work. Please learn to use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Comment: Your github repository lacks some open source license, and some *minimal* documentation (in written English, perhaps some `README.md` file) about what your project is supposed to do. **The bug is in your code** (not inside `cpp`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's temporary and I've created that just for the discussion about this thread.I'll add the docs later.And I know GDB for basic debugging.The problem was much simpler.I forgot to delete the newline character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m_path` probably contains a newline character (`\n`) at the end, as `fgets` does not remove it. Overwrite the first newline character at the end with a 0-byte.

That method to find the file name is pretty ugly and depends on external tools; I'd recommend searching for the file directly in the C++ code (possibly using the `std::filesystem` API)

Comment: That's it ! I replaced the newline character with "\0" via **string::replace** and that worked.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation of [fopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html). Failure is possible.

Prefer using [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) instead of [popen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) on [find(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html). It is safer and faster. See [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)

When that function fails, it sets [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and then you can use [perror(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)

So you should at least code:

```
FILE *fp2 = fopen("/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00"
                  "/device:01/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/capacity" , 
            "r");

if (!fp2) { 
    perror("failed to get battery capacity"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
};
```

If you get `No such file or directory` you know the reason of that failure.

You might need to read more about [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd).

Use also some terminal emulator to run a shell command such as

```
/bin/ls -l /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
```

in parallel with your program.

Take several days to read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). You should be interested in using both [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), and [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) in some other terminal emulator.

You'll take advantage in reading a good [*operating system textbook*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/).

Comment: **fopen: No such file or directory**

Comment: So why no such file or directory when the file is there? Why can I open that in the second C program?

Comment: Ask your system administrator.

Comment: I'm my system administrator :) .Isn't it related to the fact that it's a shared object not an executable? And I think it's not related to systemd at all.The program hasn't any interaction with that by any means in its whole execution process.

Comment: Without knowing the source code of your application, I can just leave you to guess.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi It fails because your filename has a \n character, or other whitespace in it. You have to use the exact filename. You are using a combination of find and grep, and that will output one line, you read in that line with fgets() which also reads the newline character

Comment: @nos You're right.Grep always puts a newline at the end.I ignored that.